# How to add pattern to validate not white spaces only in html pattern?

Tags: html

I want to validate that a client add any value into an input but can't add only white spaces. The client can put numbers, letters or characters and also white spaces between words.

```
<input class="form-control" 
       name="description" 
       placeholder="Add your description" 
       ng-model="$ctrl.description" 
       pattern="^[\\S]([\\wéáíóúñÑ,.:-¿?!() ])+$" 
       required>
```

What can I put in the pattern to validate that in html code?.

Comment: are you looking for angular specific validation or html5 validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited Answer:**

You could simply use the regex `[\w,./_=?-]+`.

*Regex explanation with breakdown:*
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
`\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
`,.` matches a single character in the list `,.`
`/` matches the character `/` literally
`_=?-` matches a single character in the list `_=?-`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.checkSpace = function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 32 && typeof $scope.inputBox === 'undefined') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

```css
.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <input class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Add your description" ng-model="inputBox" ng-keydown="checkSpace($event)" pattern="[\w,./_=?-]+" required>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice that `ng-invalid` class will be added to the element if its value has only space(s).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how can I avoid that the first value of an input being a white space?

Comment: @JVM Sounds like you want to allow space in your value later but not as the first character. I have updated my answer above. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem, but this is only for numbers and letters, when you put a symbol like ",./_=?-" this pattern doesn't work.

Comment: @JVM In that case, you need to change the regex that we are using. Please check the edited answer. Make sure that you understand the code, you are welcome to ask any questions. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

For basic html5 validation, use the following snippet. Note, title will be displayed as the error description to the end user.

```html
<input class="form-control" 
       name="description" 
       placeholder="Add your description" 
       ng-model="$ctrl.description" 
       pattern=".*\S+.*"
       title="Description is required"
       type="text"
       required>
```

Comment: why not `pattern=".*\S.*"`?